# C++ map template does not insert

Tags: c++, mathematical-optimization

I'm using a map template called ITV with a defined struct as key value and a set of pairs of integers as map value. For any reason the insert command simply doesn't work for some key value.

I have reduced my code to the smallest possible, but it is still large. It can be compiled and executed, and returns one line whenever one pair is added to the map value of some domain, indicating the key value and the size of the associated map value at that time.

Unfortunately, at some point of the function `intervals()` (at case initial arc) the insert command does nothing:

`ITV[Domain(PairStr,q)].insert(make_pair(t,t)); // ERROR! DOES NOT WORK`

I guess this may be related to some internal ordering of the map class, because the error is made only whenever the `PairStr` is `("INI", "A")`, the only case with `PairStr.first > PairStr.second`, but I really don't have any idea about this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

typedef set<pair<string,string> > SPS;
typedef set<pair<string,string> >::iterator SPSIt;

struct Domain {
    string i;
    string j;
    int q;
    Domain() : i("NaNode"), j("NaNode"), q(-1) {}
    Domain(string oi, string oj, int oq) : i(oi), j(oj), q(oq) {}
    Domain(pair<string,string> ops, int oq) : i(ops.first), j(ops.second), q(oq) {} 
    bool operator< (Domain const &domain) const {
        return i < domain.i || j < domain.j || q < domain.q;
    }
};

// GRAPH STRUCTURE
SPS ARCS, INIT_ARCS, DEST_ARCS, TOTAL_ARCS;
map<Domain ,set<pair<int,int> > > ITV;

// TIME and SO ON
int T_MAX, Q_MAX; // number of periods and stages
vector<int> STG_first; // first and last period of stage q
vector<int> STG_last;

void intervals(){
    pair<string,string> PairStr; // auxiliar variable

    // loop for generating intervals
    for(SPSIt it = TOTAL_ARCS.begin(); it != TOTAL_ARCS.end(); ++it)
        for(int q = 0; q < Q_MAX; ++q)
            for(int t = STG_first[q]; t<= STG_last[q]; ++t){
                PairStr = *it;

                // Case regular arc
                if (ARCS.count(PairStr)){
                    for(int v = t; v <= STG_last[q]; ++v){
                        ITV[Domain(PairStr,q)].insert(make_pair(t,v));
                        cout << "Size of " << PairStr.first << "-" << PairStr.second << " at " << q << ": " << ITV[Domain(PairStr,q)].size() << endl;
                    }
                // Case initial arc
                } else if (INIT_ARCS.count(PairStr)){
                    ITV[Domain(PairStr,q)].insert(make_pair(t,t)); // ERROR! DOES NOT WORK
                    cout << "Size of " << PairStr.first << "-" << PairStr.second << " at " << q << ": " << ITV[Domain(PairStr,q)].size() << endl;

                // Case destination arc
                } else if (DEST_ARCS.count(PairStr) && q > 0){
                    ITV[Domain(PairStr,q)].insert(make_pair(t,t));
                    cout << "Size of " << PairStr.first << "-" << PairStr.second << " at " << q << ": " << ITV[Domain(PairStr,q)].size() << endl;
                }
    }// end loop
}// end intervals()

int main (){
    // read arcs
    ARCS.insert(make_pair("A", "B"));
    TOTAL_ARCS.insert(make_pair("A", "B"));
    INIT_ARCS.insert( make_pair("INI", "A"));
    TOTAL_ARCS.insert(make_pair("INI", "A"));
    DEST_ARCS.insert( make_pair("B", "DES"));
    TOTAL_ARCS.insert(make_pair("B", "DES"));

    // read number of periods and stages
    T_MAX = 3;
    Q_MAX = 2;
    STG_first = vector<int> (Q_MAX);
    STG_last  = vector<int> (Q_MAX); 
    STG_first[0] = STG_last[0] = 0;
    STG_first[1] = 1;
    STG_last[1] = 2;

    intervals();
    return 0;
}   // END main
```

The desired output would be the following:

```
Size of A-B at 0: 1
Size of A-B at 1: 1
Size of A-B at 1: 2
Size of A-B at 1: 3
Size of B-DES at 1: 1
Size of B-DES at 1: 2
Size of INI-A at 0: 1
Size of INI-A at 1: 1
Size of INI-A at 1: 2
```

But the current output is this one:

```
Size of A-B at 0: 1
Size of A-B at 1: 1
Size of A-B at 1: 2
Size of A-B at 1: 3
Size of B-DES at 1: 1
Size of B-DES at 1: 2
Size of INI-A at 0: 0
Size of INI-A at 1: 0
Size of INI-A at 1: 0
```

Sorry for the long post, I would appreciate any hint about this.

Comment: I have a suspicion that the `operator<` doesn't fulfill the requirements for an ordering of the elements. For example both when `i == domain.i` or when `i > domain.i` we use the value of `j < domain` as the result.

Comment: @BoPersson that's exactly it.

Comment: When run using Visual Studio 2017, a nasty "debug assertion" window pops up saying you have an invalid comparator.  Upvoting Mr. Persson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `operator <` doesn't satisfy `std::map`'s requirements. In particular, you can have a pair of `Domain`s that are both less than each other

Consider

```
Domain A("1", "2", 0);
Domain B("2", "1", 0);

std::cout << std::boolalpha << "A < B " << (A < B) << std::endl;
std::cout << std::boolalpha << "B < A " << (B < A) << std::endl;
```

The simplest way to synthesise a (total) order from a struct's members is to assemble them into a [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp), which forms a lexicographic order of the members.

```
bool Domain::operator<( const Domain & other ) {
    return std::tie(i, j, q) < std::tie(other.i, other.j, other.q);
}
```